# Why YouTube Data API i18nRegions have only 104 regions in list when there is more regions in world

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I am fetching regions list via https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/i18nRegions API then it returns only 104 countries when having more countries in world

Please help or let me know if something wrong I am doing

How can I fetch all countries then?

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

Because in some countries it's not allowed.